# brick jointer with springy blades

Tags: tools, brick, mortar

I saw a video where the mortar on brick steps was being repaired. The jointer being used had flexible, springy blade-tips, not rigid ones. I'm looking for the name of that tool. What is that style called?

Answer (score 2):

You apparently saw a video where a **flexible finger pointing trowel** was in use. These find use also in tuck pointing work.

[image]

<sub>*(Picture Source: [https://www.amazon.com/Stainless-Finger-Pointing-Flexible-Jointer/dp/B00ZMGLMMM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZMGLMMM) )*</sub>

Comment: It actually had the standard S-shape, where the opposite ends have different widths.

Comment: @TRomano - Tools do come in various forms. At a minimum you now have something to go on.